# botocore.exceptions.ConfigParseError: Unable to parse config file Failed to execute script '__main__' due to unhandled exception

Tags: deployment, yaml

I m trying to deploy but I m getting error saying "botocore.exceptions.ConfigParseError: Unable to parse config file: /home/vsts/.aws/credentials
[1777] Failed to execute script '**main**' due to unhandled exception!" May I know why this error will come and how to rectify it

My deploy file
parameters:

- name: environment
  displayName: environment
  type: string

jobs:

- deployment: deploy_SDA_Newzealand_${{ parameters.environment }}
  displayName: Deploy SDA Newzealand service to '${{ parameters.environment }}' environment
  environment: bp-sda-newzealand-${{ parameters.environment }}-env
  variables:

  - template: ../common/iac-vars.yaml
    parameters:
    environment: ${{ parameters.environment }}
    strategy:
    runOnce:
    deploy:
    steps:
    - checkout: self

    ```
    - download: none

    - task: DownloadPipelineArtifact@2
      displayName: Download Pipeline Artifacts
      inputs:
        artifactName: 'SDA-Newzealand-${{ parameters.environment }}'
        path: "$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)"

    - task: ExtractFiles@1
      displayName: Extract Build Artifacts
      inputs:
        archiveFilePatterns: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/.aws-sam/build.zip'
        destinationFolder: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/.aws-sam/build'

    - task: awsTokenBroker@1
      displayName: Retrieve temporary AWS credentials
      inputs:
        serviceConnection: ${{ variables.serviceConnection }}
        roleName: ${{ variables.awsRole }}
        region: ${{ variables.awsRegion }}

    - script: |
        # Set Up AWS Environment
        AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=$(AWS.AccessKeyId)
        AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=$(AWS.SecretAccessKey)
        AWS_SESSION_TOKEN=$(AWS.SessionToken)
        AWS_REGION=$(AWS.Region)

        if [ ! -d ~/.aws ]; then
          mkdir ~/.aws
        fi

        # touch ~/.aws/config
        echo "[${{ variables.roleName }}]" > ~/.aws/credentials
        echo "aws_access_key_id = ${AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID}" >> ~/.aws/credentials
        echo "aws_secret_access_key = ${AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY}" >> ~/.aws/credentials
        echo "aws_session_token = ${AWS_SESSION_TOKEN}" >> ~/.aws/credentials
        echo "region = ${AWS_REGION}" >> ~/.aws/credentials
      displayName: Configure AWS Environment

    - task: AWSShellScript@1
      displayName: AWS SAM Deploy
      inputs:
        scriptType: 'inline'
        inlineScript: |
          RDSSecret=${{ variables.RDSSecret }
          export SAM_CLI_TELEMETRY=0
          sam deploy --no-fail-on-empty-changeset --stack-name ${{ variables.stackName }} --capabilities CAPABILITY_AUTO_EXPAND CAPABILITY_IAM --s3-bucket ${{ variables.artifactsBucket }} --region ${{ variables.awsRegion }} --parameter-overrides PermissionsBoundaryArn=${{ variables.PermissionsBoundaryArn }}
    ```